# FCC Per Unit Factory Test For Intentional Radiators

Tags: fcc, emissions

Can someone clarify if each unit for an intentional radiator must perform factory emission testing or is this only required for a one time tst in an approved test lab?  Is this tied to a specific  part 15 requirement?  I am involved with a 2.5 GHz low power ISM device.

Answer (score 2):

Testing is done once, per product variant. Consider this, FCC tests cost thousand of dollars to perform. Does your consumer BT device cost thousands of dollars?